# Not able to get a text like to show in Tkinter Text widget interpreting the space characters

Tags: tkinter, text, widget, character, space

```
def search():
    converted_info_from_file_to_dictionary = {}
    with open('file.txt') as working_file:  
        for line in working_file:
            key, value = line.strip().split("|--|") 
            converted_info_from_file_to_dictionary[key] = (value)
            print(converted_info_from_file_to_dictionary)
        entered = textentry.get()
        output.delete("1.0", END)
    
 
        try:
            to_be_updated = converted_info_from_file_to_dictionary[entered]
        
    
        except:
            to_be_updated = "Sorry no Info \n available !!!\n"
        output.insert("1.0", to_be_updated)
```

the info is saved in a dictionary line this {'any text': 'text with space \n\n line characters which i want \n\n to show'}

want to display like below in the Text widget area:

"text with space

line characters which i want

to show"

Answer (score 0):

That means you have literal "\n" in your text file. Using "\n" to indicate a newline character is only supposed to work in source code. However python does include a function to convert it: `ast.literal_eval`.

```
from ast import literal_eval
# ...
converted_info_from_file_to_dictionary[key] = literal_eval(value)
```

This is a hack ... it would be much better if you saved your data in a format like .json which does all of this conversion for you, instead of reinventing it yourself.